# Корректна ли фраза: «признание права на жилище произошло в 20 веке»?

Tags: стилистика

Корректна ли фраза: «признание права на жилище произошло в 20 веке»?

Answer (score 2):

Вполне.
Вас смущает "признание произошло"? Признание - это событие, оно вполне могло произойти.
А главное, я не вижу, чем заменить, не меняя смысла.
Разве что "право на жилище было признано".